# Angular unit test not correctly calling API service method from spy object

Tags: angular, jasmine

I have the following component and spec file, attempting to test a service call that hits an API endpoint and returns a string, based on an id. Based on the `employerId` I am passing in, I would expect "Enrollment Employer" to be returned and set to `employerName`. This test is always failing with the error `Expected undefined to be 'Enrollment Employer'`

I can debug and view the correct `employerId` being passed in to getEmployerName() but I'm not receiving a response. Am I writing this test correctly?

Spec:

```
  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(EnrollmentComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    debugElement = fixture.debugElement;

    employerService = debugElement.injector.get(EmployerService);
    employerSpy = spyOn(employerService, 'getEmployerName').and.callThrough();

    fixture.detectChanges();
  });


  it('should call the employer service and return the employer name', () => {
    component.employerId = 12485;
    component.getEmployerName();
    expect(employerSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(component.employerName).toBe('Enrollment Employer');
  })
```

Component:

```
  getEmployerName() {
    this.employerService.getEmployerName(this.employerId).subscribe(res => {
      this.employerName = res.empName;
    });
  }
```

Service:

```
  getEmployerName(employerId: number) {
    const url = `${this.url}getEmployerName?employerId=${employerId}`
    return this.apiService.request<any>({ url, method: HttpReqMethod.GET })
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `fakeAsync` and `flush` to wait for the API call.

```
it('should call the employer service and return the employer name', fakeAsync(() => {
    component.employerId = 12485;
    component.getEmployerName();
    flush();
    expect(employerSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
    expect(component.employerName).toBe('Enrollment Employer');
}));
```

You can also fake the API call to save time!

```
 beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(EnrollmentComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    debugElement = fixture.debugElement;

    employerService = debugElement.injector.get(EmployerService);
    employerSpy = spyOn(employerService, 'getEmployerName').and.returnValue(of({empName: 'test'}));

    fixture.detectChanges();
  });


  it('should call the employer service and return the employer name', fakeAsync(() => {
      component.employerId = 12485;
      component.getEmployerName();
      flush();
      expect(employerSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
      expect(component.employerName).toBe('Enrollment Employer');
  }));
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm still not getting the unfaked API call to return anything besides undefined but faking it is working for me. Appreciate the help.